# Compile-time performance difference between if(flag) and if(flag !=0)?

Tags: c, if-statement, optimization, boolean, embedded

Is there any performance difference between

```
if (flag) {...}
```

or

```
if (flag!=0) {...}
```

Considering both compiler execution time or resources needed.

Comment: Types, types...

Comment: To clarify, you're not asking about the resulting code being generated by the compiler, but about the compilation process itself?

Comment: More text means the compiler has to parse more text. Might be a couple of nanoseconds in difference there.

Comment: @Some programmer dude YES

Comment: Then yes there's a difference, but you need an *extremely* high resolution clock to be able to notice the difference. Or have millions or even *tens* of millions of such statements in a single source file. And there might even not *be* a (measurable) difference, since the the compiler must do different things for the two different expressions, and those differences might outweigh each other.

Comment: To be fair, the author is clearly asking about the _performance differences_ of the two approaches, while the linked duplicate seems exclusively about questions of style, readability, maintenance, etc. The author could have made it clear in the title though, rather than leaving it to the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no practical difference, if flag is an integral type.